# Can I delete an app I got on sale?

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, delete, paid-apps

I recently downloaded an app for free from Google play store. It usually costs $0.99, but is now free.
If I were to delete it, will google remember that I purchased it, even though I paid nothing? Can I delete it now, and install it later without purchasing it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bochur's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190492/131553) is correct. By way of additional information in your Play Store → Account → Order History , these apps will be shown as **0** price payment apps as the screenshot below shows - all these apps (barring third) were bought free (discounted) and I can install them again on any device (of course with the same account)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From play store [support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?hl=en&ref_topic=3365058&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=0):

> You can use apps you bought on Google Play on any Android device
>   without paying again. However, each device must have the same Google
>   Account on it.
>
> You can:
>
> - **Reinstall an app you bought but deleted**
> - Install an app on more than one Android device.
> - Install an app on a new Android device.

Even though the app you downloaded was free now, being that usually it is a paid app, Google will count it as if you paid $0.00 and therefore it's counted as if you bought it. And as quoted above, purchased apps can be reinstalled later.

Comment: +1. Agreed. With experience I can say that I bought [this game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ustwo.monumentvalley&hl=en) for free, uninstalled it some time later and I still get to reinstall it whenever I choose to.

Comment: +1 added a screenshot to supplement your answer